# getting error in beamer "Enviroment theindex undefined"

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

For the following tex, I get the error that "Enviroment theindex undefined". I did not use index in any part of my .tex. But still when I use "\newenvironment{theindex}" or "\renewenvironment{theindex}" it says theindex has been already defined. What is your suggestion?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,algorithm,ifthen,algorithmic,epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}
\hspace{1cm}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Your code won't compile because you're loading the package `tocbibind`
that's doing something with a table of contents/index, which naturally isn't defined for a set of slides. So all is well after one comments out the offending package, which you don't need.

As an aside, yours is not quite a *minimal* working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,algorithm,ifthen,algorithmic} %,epsfig
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}     \hspace{1cm}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame} 
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,scale=0.3,minimum size=1em}}\tikzset{edge/.style = {-,> = latex'}}
        \node [black] at (1,0) {$m_2$}; \node [black,rotate=90] at (0,1) {$m_1$};
        \node [black,rotate=90] at (0,-1) {$m_3$};\node [black] at (-1,0) {$m_4$};
        \draw [black](-0.15,0) rectangle (.15,2);%m_1
        \draw [black] (-0.15,0) rectangle (.15,-2);%m_3
        \draw [black] (0.15,.15) rectangle (2,-.15);\draw [black] (-0.15,.15) rectangle (-2,-.15);
        \node[vertex] (a1) at  (2,0.25) {};\node[vertex] (a2) at  (2,-0.25) {};
        \node[vertex] (b1) at  (-2,0.25) {};\node[vertex] (c1) at  (0.25,-2) {};
        \node[vertex] (c2) at  (-0.25,-2) {};\node[vertex] (d2) at  (0.25,2) {};
        \node[vertex] (d1) at  (-0.75,2) {};\node[vertex] (d3) at  (-0.25,2) {};
        \node [blue] at (.25,2.5) {$j_3$};\node [black!30!green] at  (-0.75,2.5) {$j_1$};
        \node [red] at  (-0.25,2.5) {$j_2$};\node [purple] at  (0.25,-2.5) {$j_4$};
        \draw[edge][thick][black!30!green] (d1) [->][out=-90, in=0] to (b1);
        \draw[edge][thick][blue] (d2) [->][out=-90, in=180] to (a1);
        \draw[edge][thick][red] (d3) [->] to (c2);
        \draw[edge][thick][purple](c1) [->][out=90, in=180] to (a2);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{frame}     
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. I edited my question.

Comment: note that my code compiles fine.